# How to make professional tabs for a game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed this youtube video exactly on how to make some professional tabs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvzZjg-uP2k&t=241s

But my code didn't turn out the same way. I want it like theirs so i can scroll through the different tabs and make a separate html file for each one

I have tried following the video ( new at css) and i think i formatted it correctly

Here is my css/ html code:

Css code:

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    background: #efefef;
    font-family: arial;
}
.nav_bar {
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 860px;
   padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    height: 64px
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.nav_bar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav_bar ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.nav_bar ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    background: #6db1e4;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 23px 20px 22px 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    width: 75px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav_bar ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    background: #96e0e9;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
    transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
}
.nav_bar ul li a#onlink {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.nav_bar ul li a#onlink:hover;{
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
.main_container{
    margin auto;
    width: 860px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    min-height: 400px;
    border-top: none;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.main_container p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

My html code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Basic Clicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body
      <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="skilltree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
            <li><a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
            <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="quests.html">Quests</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_container">
        <p> This is the home page.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the html link to look like what he has at the end of the video, but the actual output is a bit off and cant scroll through the pages http://prntscr.com/nrkf6v   this is my output not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't formatted it correctly.

You had 5 or 6 CSS errors and a big one in HTML. (`<body` tag wasn't closed). As a rule of thumb, in web, every character counts. There are some exceptions, but that's exactly what they are: exceptions.

The rule is: "every mistake breaks something".
Here's the correct output.

The tool you want to check your code against is called validator. (HTML validator, CSS validator, etc...). Or you can use an IDE (a smart editor which understands and suggests code as you type, also letting you know when it thinks you've made a mistake, considering current web standards).

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: arial;
}

.nav_bar {
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav_bar ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_bar ul li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav_bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background: #6db1e4;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 23px 20px 22px 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  width: 75px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background: #96e0e9;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
}

.nav_bar ul li a#onlink {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.nav_bar ul li a#onlink:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

.main_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  min-height: 400px;
  border-top: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.main_container p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Basic Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="skilltree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
      <li><a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
      <li><a href="pets.html">Pets</a></li>
      <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="quests.html">Quests</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main_container">
    <p> This is the home page.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks. im really new at this trying to convert my long python game to html so i can upload it to a website

Comment: We all started somewhere. Best of luck. And don't worry over it. I sometimes make typos and lose hours over them. The more complex the code you're writing, the harder to pinpoint typos. It's part of programming. But, luckily, there are tools to help along.

Comment: sorry i didn't accept your answer im going back through and doing that for all my questions